# bbPress sidebar not showing in child theme Twenty Fourteen

Tags: wordpress, themes, sidebar, bbpress

I followed the instructions here:
https://codex.bbpress.org/layout-and-functionality-examples-you-can-use/#26-creating-a-bbpress-specific-sidebar

This is my code from the child theme:

```
sidebar.php - https://dpaste.de/pRuO

function.php - https://dpaste.de/8uCg

this is the widget dashboard - https://i.imgur.com/k6KdacU.png
```

here is the sidebar.php child theme code:

```
<div id="secondary">
    <?php
        $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        if ( ! empty ( $description ) ) :
    ?>
    <h2 class="site-description"><?php echo esc_html( $description ); ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary' ) ) : ?>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navigation site-navigation secondary-navigation">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) && !is_bbpress() ) : ?>
    lalala
    <div id="primary-sidebar" class="primary-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->    
    <?php elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'bbp-sidebar' ) && is_bbpress() ) : ?>    
    mamama
    <div id="secondary" class="primary-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'bbp-sidebar' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->    
    <?php else : ?>    
    hahaha    
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->
```

It is executing the "lalala" condition in my domain.com/forum page.

I am using a child theme for Twenty Fourteen.

How can I enable the forum bbpress sidebar (on the right and not replace the original sidebar)? Here is my forum website http://harta.net/forum if you need to check it

UPDATE:

the condition below are both false, why is that ?

```
is_active_sidebar( 'bbp-sidebar' ) = false
is_bbpress() = fase
```

Comment: Paste your code into the question please.

Comment: its there, i re-edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: You need to have the code shown in your question not a link to somewhere else with the code displaying.

Comment: ok done. can you review

Comment: I can't see your code where you have registered the sidebar "bbp-sidebar"

Comment: is function.php ? im not sure. sorry im a noob in wordpress. but i think its in here https://dpaste.de/8uCg

Comment: i put the live forum link as well, if you want i can chat

Comment: The sidebar will only show if the page you are viewing is a BB Press page.

Comment: isnt that a bbpress page ? i did do a test on the condition, it didnt go to condition 2 either. also i would like the original sidebar plus bbpress sidebar on the right, not replacing the original sidebar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167040/discussion-between-andrew-schultz-and-axil).